# How to select button in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to select button in angular

Here is my code from template.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let lib of library; let i=index">
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="library-{{i}}" name="lib-books"
             (change)="selectOnChange($event)"
             [value]="lib">
      <label for="library-{{i}}"></label>
    </div>
    <label for="library-{{i}}">{{lib}}</label>
  </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please share your library array

Comment: Why don't you start by creating a func "selectOnRadio(ev)" and interrogate?

Comment: @bresleveloper if i would know, i would have done it. Can you please give me some examples, how to do this

Comment: @Shohel, library is an array of string which is coming directly coming form API.

Comment: If you want to do into ngFor, then need a object for this displaying result

Comment: You mention "After saving the form". Where is your `<form>` tag? are there any other elements in the model apart from `lib-books`?

Comment: After onNgInit write "selectOnChange(ev){ debugger; }" and run the app with f12 opened.  The browser's debugger will stop @your func and then you can write in the console "ev" to see the event value

Answer (score 1):

Create a property isSelected to your lib object and

Sets up two-way data binding to your radio button:

```
[(value)]="lib.isSelected"
```

Equivalent to:

```
(valueChange)="lib.isSelected=$event"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Form component, either [template driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Template driven: You use two-way-binding for `ngModel` to store the selected value in your form model:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  library:string[] = [
    'lib1', 'lib2', 'lib3'
  ];

  // note: you should create an interface for that
  model = {
    books: '',
  }

  onSubmit () {
    // save the selection
  }
}
```

The difference to your code: the two-way binding to the model field `[(ngModel)]="model.books"`

```
<div class="form-group" onsubmit="onSubmit()">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let lib of library; let i=index">
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="library-{{i}}" name="lib-books"
      [(ngModel)]="model.books"
             [value]="lib">
      <label for="library-{{i}}"></label>
    </div>
    <label for="library-{{i}}">{{lib}}</label>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And don't forget to import the `forms` module in `app.module.ts`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ FormsModule ],
})
```

Check out the [StackBlitz for the template driven solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dncp4q)

Reactive forms (my personal preference, especially with the form builder):

```
export class AppComponent {
  library: string[] = [
    'lib1', 'lib2', 'lib3'
  ];

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private __fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.__fb.group({
      book: ''
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // save the selection
  }
}
```

Note: the `name` attribute of the `<input>` needs to be the same as the `formControlName` and the `<form>` tag needs a `[formGroup]` binding.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" onsubmit="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let lib of library; let i=index">
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio"
                    [value]="lib" 
                    name="book"
                    formControlName="book" 
                    id="library-{{i}}"
                >
            </div>
            <label for="library-{{i}}">{{lib}}</label>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</form>
```

Check out the [StackBlitz for the reactive solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwrdmh)